# How to check the data is bind to DOM in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, dom

I'm a newbie on AngularJS, so apologies if this question is too obvious:

I'm developing an AngularJS app which gets data from [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) (as jSON).

Snippet of the JSON:

```
{
  "-JEwtuuyDQzKxGAcOB-L" : {
    "date" : 1391517477,
    "filter" : "video",
    "type" : "instagram",
    "url" : "http://instagram.com/example",
    "title" : "#textile #materials #test This is a test",
    "author" : "teknotica",
    "image" : "http://image.jpg"
  }
}
```

Data is bind to the DOM and printed, all works fine. My aim now is to add a loader to be hidden when the data is all bind to the DOM.

My question is: where or how do I check that state? How do I know all the data is printed in the front end?

A snippet of my code here:

```
angular.module("appFeed", ["firebase"])
  .factory("appService", ["$firebase", function($firebase) {


    var ref = new Firebase("my_app_url"); 
        ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {        
        // Thought this was the place where I could check data is ready
    });

    return $firebase(ref);

  }])
  .controller("AppController", ["$scope", "appService",
    function($scope, appService) {

      $scope.feed_items = appService;

    }    
  ]);
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: write a sample of your data. Is there any data manipulation when you get it from firebase? You need to use $timeout to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @JayShukla, thanks for your response. No, there is no data manipulation of the data. See my edited post to see how the jSON looks like. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, can you tell me when exactly you want to show loading image? On first time load or after loading when there is a change in data?

Comment: Only on first load :)

Comment: Using promise you can achieve this. See my answer. You need to use $timeout if you want any manipulation after you get data. $timeout updates UI without waiting to complete current function execution. whatever you write inside $timeout will execute inside new turn (separate from the current function)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this. Make div in your HTML to show loading text or image whatever you want and just hide/show it using ngShow/ngHide directive.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-show="showLoading">Loading...</div>
<div ng-hide="showLoading">Your data will be here</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module("appFeed", ["firebase"])
  .factory("appService", ["$firebase", function($firebase) {


    var ref = new Firebase("my_app_url"); 
        ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {        


    });

    return $firebase(ref);

  }])
  .controller("AppController", ["$scope", "appService",
    function($scope, appService) {
      var appHandle = appService;

      appHandle.then(function(data) {
           $scope.feed_items = data;
           $scope.showLoading = false;
      });

      $scope.showLoading = true;

    }    
  ]);
```

Comment: Jay, thanks for your quick reply. I tried your code and I'm having this error:

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'then'

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution doing the following:

```
.controller("AppController", ["$scope", "appService", "$firebase",
    function($scope, appService, $firebase) {

      var ref = new Firebase("my_app_url");

      $scope.asset = $firebase(ref);
      $scope.asset.$on('loaded', function(items) {
              // Items has been loaded!
      });
});
```